# Regex in Java Script: match spaces after 1-3 character words

Tags: javascript, regex

For fun I'm making js function that would sweep through html file and would add non breaking spaces after words, that should be pushed to the next line, eg "and", "or" etc. I'm using replace on string containing entire HTML text and I can't seem to create regex that would match just the space after these words. I've tried to use positive lookbehind, like that:

```
(?<=[\u0020|\u00A0|\u000A][a-z]{1,3})[\u0020|\u00A0|\u000D]
```

where the first group should match spaces and three character words but exclude them from the final match, while the second group should match either space or next line, that would be changed to non breaking space. Clearly I don't understand something as this is not working.

Desired match of two character words in following string:

```
To make a good app I need to get better.
```

would be spaces after "To", "a", "I" and "to".

Comment: Aren't `app` and `get` three-letter words as well? Perhaps you might use a whitelist of words instead of "any one to three letters".

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean, let me try it and I'll tell if it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
/(?:\b\w{1,2})(\s)/
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/7aIudD/3)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working, 1 or 2 character words are being matched along with the following spaces. Again - this is for Java Script in browser.

Comment: yeah you have to take group1

Comment: What exactly does it mean to take group1?

Comment: you can capture some part of of matched string using capturing group in regex.